# Boot camp attempting to boot off wrong MBP internal drive

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, ssd

I have an early 2011 17-inch MBP running the latest version of Mavericks. The primary drive is a 1TB SSD and I also have a 512GB SSD in the optical bay. BootCamp is installed on a partition on the primary drive, however when I attempt to boot into BC I get a black screen with a blinking cursor. If I remove the 512GB drive, however, BC launches properly. (Also, in case it makes a difference, the BC partition does not show up in the Startup Disk preference panel but does show up in the EFI list on startup.)

The primary drive shows up as disk1, while the drive in the optical bay shows up as disk0. What I suspect is happening is that the MBP is attempting to boot Windows from disk0, which causes a problem when the 512GB drive is installed. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this.

Is my theory about what's happening a reasonable one? Is there somewhere in the Mac that the drive assignment for BC is set that I can change? Any help is greatly appreciated...this has been driving me crazy for a while now!

Answer (score 1):

According to a few people on the Apple Forums (https://discussions.apple.com/message/22626184#22626184) it is not possible to use windows on the 2nd drive (disk1).

Perhaps put Windows on the SSD, at least the System, and create a NTFS partition on your HDD for large files.

Comment: Thanks, but I have two SSDs and the BootCamp partition is on the primary boot drive (which for some reason is being assigned as disk1).

Comment: It needs to be on disk0 I believe

Answer (score 0):

I use Mac OS on an SSD and Ubuntu and Win7 on the 2nd HDD. Diskutil throw me this :

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS 10.9                    249.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS X                870.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 79.9 GB    disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Ubuntu                  50.0 GB    disk1s4
```

But I use refit to handle the booting. Maybe you should try :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try refit but had the same problem.